# IPB display the current year in template

Tags: php, ipb

I use the IPB (Invision Power Board) 4.1.12.2 and I need to display the current year in the template.

I tried the next:

```
<?php echo date('Y'); ?>
{{date('Y');}}
{date('Y')}
```

and, even:

```
<php>
$var = date('Y');
</php>

{$var}
```

but I don't have any result. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it show anything?

Comment: errors or just the raw text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. It was easy:

```
{{$var = date('Y');}}

{$var}
```